# mlflow warning: Experiment ID mismatch for exp Iris. ID recorded as ‘1’ in metadata…

Tags: python, warnings, mlflow

I’m completely new to mlflow.

I’ve started with a couple of the standard tutorials and created examples using the well-known Iris and wine-quality datasets and named the experiments accordingly.

When I run my code I get warnings:

```
WARNING:root:Experiment ID mismatch for exp iris.  ID recorded as ‘1’ in meta data.  Experiment will be ignored.

NoneType: None

WARNING:root:Experiment ID mismatch for exp mlruns. ID recorded as ‘8’ in meta data.  Experiment will be ignored.

NoneType: None

WARNING:root:Experiment ID mismatch for exp wine-quality. ID recorded as ‘5’ in meta data.  Experiment will be ignored.

NoneType: None
```

However, when I run the following in a jupyter notebook cell:

```
From mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient

client=Mlflow.Client()

experiments=client.list_experiments()

experiments
```

I see the list of experiments, including the 3 above, whose ID matches their names.

When I look in the `mlruns/wine-quality/1` folder says, the `meta.yaml` states correctly that `Experiment id` is 5.

Can someone help explain why I am getting these warnings?

(When I run `mlflow ui —backend-store-uri file:C:/Users/jb8/mlruns` I see the experimental runs being logged as I’d hope…)

Comment: From which path you are running the script? Perhaps it's different from where the notebook is?

Comment: It turns out it's largely operator error - I was going too far into the directory structure to run the command.